# Removing Duplex Fields Based On Two Fixed Entries

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Below is SQL command that I have found in another post, which is a good start for me but I do not know much SQL, I mainly just use PHPMyAdmin to do everything. But I have a number of different fields to check. What I need is to find any duplex entries on a selected 'Job_id' where the 'date' (timestamp field) is the same on a given user 'user_id'.

```
SELECT varchar_col
FROM table
GROUP BY varchar_col
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

I hope I have been clear. Please let me know if I have not been and I try and re-word it!

Glenn.

Answer (score 1):

```
select job_id
from temp.new_table
where user_id=123
group by user_id, date
having count(*) > 1
```

Table data

```
'1', '2012-08-13 20:40:21', '123' ||
'1', '2012-08-13 20:40:21', '123' ||
'2', '2012-08-13 20:40:21', '123'
```

output

```
job_id
 1
```

I hope this is what you wanted